# AND OR Clauses in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write such a Query :

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE ID = id AND Text != text OR Text = text
```

I mean `ID = id` clause and `Text != text` clause should be combined with and, and they should be combined with **`OR`** with the last clause. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What are `Text` and `text`? Are they different columns in a case sensitive collation? If so that seems confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (ID = id AND Text != text) OR Text = text
```

You should always use parentheses when combining `and` and `or`

Comment: @MartinSmith, true, I was thinking about `joins`. Clearly that's not the case here. I'm assuming they are different fields, which of course begs the question why are there 2 fields with nearly identical name?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (ID = id AND Text != text) OR Text = text
```

Use brackets to separate two clauses

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   db
WHERE  (ID = id AND TEXT != TEXT)
       OR 
       OR TEXT = TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (ID = id AND Text != text) OR Text = text
```

Answer (score 0):

USE Logical Operator (AND/OR) :

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (ID = id AND Text != text) OR Text = text
```

or you can use CASE :

```
SELECT * FROM db where 
(CASE WHEN ID = id THEN (CASE WHEN Text != text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 end = 1) OR
(CASE WHEN Text = text THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT * FROM db WHERE (ID = id AND Text != text) OR Text = text